# How to implement a simple message queue?

Tags: delphi, message-queue, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to implement a message queue in a new thread, just like main thread is. I found here [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) but I don't need to display a window. So, `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow` from the exemple, are not needed for me. I don't have that info to pass to those procedures, anyway. I just want to register a window procedure `AllocateHWnd(PrivateWndProc);` and then make a loop with `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`. I don't know if this makes sense...

Comment: CreateWindow is fine. You just use a message only window. Simples. The problem with AllocateHWnd is that it isn't threadsafe and Emba refuse to fix it.

Comment: But how to tell that thread which procedure will handle messages ?

Comment: If all you need is a message queue, you don't really need a window at all, as you can use `PostThreadMessage()` to post messages to the queue, and then the thread would just need a `(Peek|Get)Message()` loop without `DispatchMessage()`. If you do use `CreateWindow()` to create a (message-only) `HWND` to receive messages with, then you need to use `RegisterClass()` to register a message procedure for it, or else use `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()`, and then you do have to `DispatchMessage()` any received message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Great ! But it's not possible to send the message and wait for it to be processed ? `PostThreadMessage` returns immediately...

Comment: @MarusNebunu [Why isn’t there a SendThreadMessage function?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081223-00/?p=19743)

Comment: @MarusNebunu you could have the receiving thread post a message back to the sender when done. Or, you could put an event object or callback function pointer in the message's `wParam`/`lParam` so the receiving thread can signal it when done. Otherwise, you will just have to create an `HWND` that you can `SendMessage()` to.

Comment: Lots of potential for trouble to send messages directly to a thread. Use a message only window created in the thread, and send or list messages to that window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a demo to show you how to create a worker thread which works mostly like the main thread.

To use the demo, create a form with 3 buttons and a memo. Then paste the code below. Look at the names I gave to the components to do the same and associate correct event handlers.

You may want to add more error checking. I made some shortcuts to make code easier to read. You should probably check everything which could fail.

In a real application, if you have several worker threads, derive all thread from my TMyThread class so that they inherit the message queue and message pump.

Since a thread cannot access the VCL and to keep things simple, I made the worker thread display messages using OutputDebugString. The messages are shown in the event view (Ctrl+Alt+V) when you run the demo under Delphi debugger.

```
unit ThreadDemoMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
    TMyThread = class(TThread)
    private
        FWinHandle : HWND;
        procedure AllocateHWnd; virtual;
        procedure DeallocateHWnd; virtual;
        procedure WndProc(var MsgRec: TMessage); virtual;
    public
        procedure Execute; override;
        property WinHandle : HWND read FWinHandle;
    end;

    TThreadDemoForm = class(TForm)
        StartThreadButton: TButton;
        Memo1: TMemo;
        StopThreadButton: TButton;
        PostMessageButton: TButton;
        Label1: TLabel;
        procedure StartThreadButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure StopThreadButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure PostMessageButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FWorkerThread : TMyThread;
        procedure WorkerThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  ThreadDemoForm: TThreadDemoForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TThreadDemoForm.PostMessageButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if not Assigned(FWorkerThread) then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Worker thread not running');
        Exit;
    end;
    PostMessage(FWorkerThread.FWinHandle, WM_USER + 2, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TThreadDemoForm.StartThreadButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(FWorkerThread) then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Worker thread already running');
        Exit;
    end;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Ask worker thread to start...');
    FWorkerThread                 := TMyThread.Create(TRUE);
    FWorkerThread.FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;
    FWorkerThread.OnTerminate     := WorkerThreadTerminate;
    FWorkerThread.Start;
end;

procedure TThreadDemoForm.StopThreadButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if not Assigned(FWorkerThread) then begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Worker thread not running');
        Exit;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Asking the worker thread to terminate...');
    PostMessage(FWorkerThread.FWinHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TThreadDemoForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    if Assigned(FWorkerThread) then begin
        FWorkerThread.OnTerminate := nil;   // Cancel event handling
        // Ask the worker thread to terminate
        PostMessage(FWorkerThread.FWinHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        FWorkerThread := nil;
        // Let the workerthread breath
        Sleep(250);
    end;
end;

procedure TThreadDemoForm.WorkerThreadTerminate(Sender : TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Worker thread Terminated');
    FWorkerThread := nil;
end;

{ TMyThread }

var
    GWndHandlerCritSect : TRTLCriticalSection;
const
    WorkerThreadWindowClassName = 'WorkerThreadWindowClass';

// WndControlWindowsProc is a callback function used for message handling
function WndControlWindowsProc(
    ahWnd   : HWND;
    auMsg   : UINT;
    awParam : WPARAM;
    alParam : LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
    Obj    : TObject;
    MsgRec : TMessage;
begin
    // When the window was created, we stored a reference to the object
    // into the storage space we asked windows to have
{$IFDEF WIN64}
    Obj := TObject(GetWindowLongPtr(ahWnd, 0));
{$ELSE}
    Obj := TObject(GetWindowLong(ahWnd, 0));
{$ENDIF}
    // Check if the reference is actually our object type
    if not (Obj is TMyThread) then
        Result := DefWindowProc(ahWnd, auMsg, awParam, alParam)
    else begin
        // Internally, Delphi use TMessage to pass parameters to his
        // message handlers.
        MsgRec.Msg    := auMsg;
        MsgRec.wParam := awParam;
        MsgRec.lParam := alParam;
        TMyThread(Obj).WndProc(MsgRec);
        Result := MsgRec.Result;
    end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.AllocateHWnd;
var
    TempClass        : TWndClass;
    NewWndClass      : TWndClass;
    ClassRegistered  : Boolean;
begin
    // Nothing to do if hidden window is already created
    if FWinHandle <> 0 then
        Exit;

    // We use a critical section to be sure only one thread can check if a
    // class is registered and register it if needed.
    // We must also be sure that the class is not unregistered by another
    // thread which just destroyed a previous window.
    EnterCriticalSection(GWndHandlerCritSect);
    try
        // Check if the window class is already registered
        NewWndClass.hInstance     := HInstance;
        NewWndClass.lpszClassName := WorkerThreadWindowClassName;
        ClassRegistered := GetClassInfo(HInstance,
                                        NewWndClass.lpszClassName,
                                        TempClass);
        if not ClassRegistered then begin
            // Not registered yet, do it right now !
            NewWndClass.style         := 0;
            NewWndClass.lpfnWndProc   := @WndControlWindowsProc;
            NewWndClass.cbClsExtra    := 0;
            NewWndClass.cbWndExtra    := SizeOf(Pointer);
            NewWndClass.hIcon         := 0;
            NewWndClass.hCursor       := 0;
            NewWndClass.hbrBackground := 0;
            NewWndClass.lpszMenuName  := nil;

           if Winapi.Windows.RegisterClass(NewWndClass) = 0 then
                raise Exception.Create(
                     'Unable to register hidden window class.' +
                     ' Error: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
        end;

        // Now we are sure the class is registered, we can create a window using it
        FWinHandle := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
                                     NewWndClass.lpszClassName,
                                     '',        // Window name
                                     WS_POPUP,  // Window Style
                                     0, 0,      // X, Y
                                     0, 0,      // Width, Height
                                     0,         // hWndParent
                                     0,         // hMenu
                                     HInstance, // hInstance
                                     nil);      // CreateParam

        if FWinHandle = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create(
                'Unable to create hidden window. ' +
                ' Error: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));    { V8.62 tell user real error. probably no memory }

        // We have a window. In the associated data, we record a reference
        // to our object. This will later allow to call the WndProc method to
        // handle messages sent to the window.
    {$IFDEF WIN64}
        SetWindowLongPtr(FWinHandle, 0, INT_PTR(Self));
    {$ELSE}
        SetWindowLong(FWinHandle, 0, Longint(Self));
    {$ENDIF}
    finally
        LeaveCriticalSection(GWndHandlerCritSect);
    end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.DeallocateHWnd;
begin
    if FWinHandle = 0 then
        Exit;              // Already done
{$IFDEF WIN64}
    SetWindowLongPtr(FWinHandle, 0, 0);
{$ELSE}
    SetWindowLong(FWinHandle, 0, 0);
{$ENDIF}
    DestroyWindow(FWinHandle);
    FWinHandle := 0;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
    MsgRec : TMsg;
begin
    // We cannot access the VCL from a thread, so use system function.
    // The message will be shown in the debugger in the events view.
    OutputDebugString('Thread Starting');

    AllocateHWnd;
    // Put a first message into the message queue
    PostMessage(FWinHandle, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);

    // Message loop
    // If GetMessage retrieves the WM_QUIT, the return value is FALSE and
    // the message loop is broken.
    while (not Terminated) and GetMessage(MsgRec, 0, 0, 0) do begin
        TranslateMessage(MsgRec);
        DispatchMessage(MsgRec)
    end;

    DeallocateHWnd;
    OutputDebugString('Thread Ending');
end;

procedure TMyThread.WndProc(var MsgRec: TMessage);
begin
    case MsgRec.Msg of
    WM_USER + 1 : OutputDebugString('WM_USER + 1');
    WM_USER + 2 : OutputDebugString('WM_USER + 2');
    else
         MsgRec.Result := DefWindowProc(FWinHandle, MsgRec.Msg,
                                        MsgRec.wParam, MsgRec.lParam);
    end;
end;

initialization
    InitializeCriticalSection(GWndHandlerCritSect);

finalization
    DeleteCriticalSection(GWndHandlerCritSect);

end.
```

Comment: Why you posted a `WM_USER+1` message in `Execute` thread method ?