# Message queueing with threads in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, message-queue, postmessage, peekmessage

I'm new at message queueing, and want to implement something like this:

- Get information from main thread
- Send to a worker thread queue
- Worker thread may just process it or send to another work thread proccess it
- Eventually callback execution to UI due some events (can handle it with synchronize mechanism)

My main problem is how to make communication between main thread and worker thread's, and between worker threads with other worker threads (to signal the main thread eventually, I can callback then synchronized).

After tons of googling, I found basically two ways to do it:

- Create a message-only `HWND`, which exchange messages between a registered `WndProc()` function. I found a perfect example of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926110/how-to-implement-a-simple-message-queue). As Remy Lebeau commented, this way may need to dispatch the message via `DispatchMessage()` (and seems to be more verbose way to do it). This way basically I use the `PostMessage()` function and process messages in the `WndProc()` function.

***Or:***

- Create a custom `TThread`-derived class with a `PeekMessage()`|`GetMessage()` loop which processes thread messages and deals with what it needs to do in its `Execute()` method. This one basically I use the `PostThreadMessage()` function and process messages in the `Execute()` method of the thread;

I successfully tested a basic demo with the two options, receiving the messages in the two ways I mentioned.

For those who have more expertise, am I on the right track? Did I miss something trying to understand how to do this?

Another question for those more experienced is, which method is the best for heavy message exchanging? And which is the best for an X situation or Y situation?

It's a more theoretical question, but thanks for those who can help.

Comment: One issue with Windows message queues for comms TO threads is that only one thread, (the queue creator/owner)? can wait.  I usually use a TObjectQueue decendant with an OS semaphore, (CreateSemaphore etc API), to count/wait the entries.  PostMessage() is fine for sending objects back to the GUI thread, so avoiding synchronize() calls:)

Comment: Why don't you use a threading library?

Comment: I use basically what you describe in the last alternative. The thread has a message loop, that is it create a HWND which is used only for messaging. The thread's Execute message pump messages from that HWND. I use WinAPI for all message related stuff so that it is thread safe. I never use PostThreadMessage, always PostMessage. When large amount of data must be exchanged (A single message has only WParam and LParam as data field), the sender allocate memory and the receiver free the memory. The message itself only carry the data pointer.

Comment: @fpiette Sorry, but I don't understand correclty. Im my **first** alternative is literally what you suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926110/how-to-implement-a-simple-message-queue): The thread creates a hidden message-only window with an associated WndProc and process messages received via `PostMessage()` there.

My **second** alternative is a `PeekMessage()|GetMessage()` infinite loop directly in `Execute()` that process messages received via `PostThreadMessage()`.

Comment: Analysing just the code and what it does in the two options I listed (I think is the only two ways to process queue e process messages in Delphi btw), I think the **second** one is faster, but as I said before, I new at message queueing stuff.

Comment: What I use is then a mix of both your alternative: a "message pump" also called a "message loop" GetMessage/DispatchMessage in the Execute method. And PostMessage anywhere a message has to be sent. Look at this code: https://svn.overbyte.be/svn/icsv9/Source/OverbyteIcsWndControl.pas

Comment: Thanks @fpiette. Your component do handle messages over a WndProc function (messages are posted via `PostMessage`), what is good for semantics, but my percption is that this is slower than use a directly message pump and handle all incoming `PostThreadMessage`, translate and dispatch messages is also needless so I handle only needed messages.
I'll try to make mechanism to see the message queue count time by time and see how it works with a heavy message flux.